# MSVC 2012: linker not using the dependency DLL

Tags: visual-studio-2012, linker, dependencies

I have two projects in the same solution (MSVC 2012): one exe and the other is dll.
The exe project depends one the dll. However when linking the exe I get 'unresolved' errors for the functions defined in dll.
Actually when looking on the Linker -> 'Command Line' of the Exe project setting I do not see my DLL project referenced there.
The option 'Linker' -> 'Link Library Dependencies' is set to Yes.

All relevant dll functions are defined as __declspec(dllexport) in the DLL and as __declspec(dllimport) in EXE.

Comment: Use the Add New Reference button to tell the build system that the EXE has a dependency on the DLL and that its import library needs to be linked.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the DLL's .lib listed in your Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies section for the executable? This is required unless you are dynamically loading the DLL via LoadLibrary.